Kubernetes VPA - Run updater Once Per Week on Specific Day
Our team runs a set of production clusters with many Deployments that overprovision lots of resources. We'd like to use a VPA to automatically lower the resource requests for containers in these Deployments, but we'd like to do so in the least disruptive way and only apply updates once per week on a specific day (e.g. Sunday) when traffic is low.
I noticed that the VPA-updater component has a updater-interval flag, but this does not allow for a specific day of week so I'm curious if there are any alternatives.
How can I configure the VPA to only run updates once per week on a specific day?
Link to Docs

Why not have VPA configured Off (see Quick start), patch it to Auto and then back to Off using a CronJob scheduled to run once per week? NB This feels like it would be disruptive to do it once per week (and on a Sunday) and I'd encourage you to consider running it continuously and educate your teams that it runs.

+1 for the suggestion. Won't it be more disruptive running it continuously instead of once per week? The reason for once per week updates is because we'd like to experiment as we already run HPAs and want to minimize the interference and competition between the two autoscalers.

You're right. running VPA continuously can lead to disruptions, especially if HPA is already in place. If you find weekly updates disruptive, change it to monthly or adjust the PodDisruptionBudget for deployments to minimize the impact of VPA-triggered restarts

You're right. running VPA continuously can lead to disruptions, especially if HPA is already in place. If you find weekly updates disruptive, change it to monthly or adjust the PodDisruptionBudget for deployments to minimize the impact of VPA-triggered restarts
DazWilkin's idea is good.
enable VPA on your cluster
az aks update --name ingress-demo-cluster --resource-group arkorg --enable-vpa


Deploy a sample nginx app
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: "512Mi"


Configure VPA for the deployment in Off Mode
apiVersion: autoscaling.k8s.io/v1
kind: VerticalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: nginx-vpa
spec:
  targetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: nginx
  updatePolicy:
    updateMode: "Off"

Create a Cron Job to patch the VPA to Auto mode on Sundays or if weekly feels too disruptive make it monthly and revert it to Off mode after an hour
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: vpa-weekly-updater
spec:
  schedule: "0 0 * * 0" # Every Sunday at midnight
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: vpa-patcher
            image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - |
              kubectl patch vpa nginx-vpa --type=json -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/updatePolicy/updateMode", "value": "Auto"}]'
              echo "Waiting for VPA updates to complete..."
              sleep 3600 # Wait for 1 hour
              kubectl patch vpa nginx-vpa --type=json -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/updatePolicy/updateMode", "value": "Off"}]'
          restartPolicy: OnFailure


Done.
kubectl get pods -l app=nginx
kubectl get vpa
kubectl create job --from=cronjob/vpa-weekly-updater vpa-test-job





Similar thread
